# SQL join and sum of items

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables

users

```
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
 1   A    
 2   B
```

orders

```
+--+--------+-------+-------+
|id|subtotal|created|user_id|
+--+--------+-------+-------+
 1  10       1000001   1
 2  20       1000002   1
 3  10       1000003   2
 4  10       1000005   1
```

The idea is to get `AVG`, `SUM` and the last created order from the users.

```
SELECT
  users.name,
  users.phone,
  SUM(a.subtotal),
  COALESCE(a.created, NULL)
  FROM users
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    orders.id,
    orders.subtotal,
    orders.user_id,
    orders.created
  FROM
    orders 
  JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(i.created) created, i.user_id 
      FROM orders i
      GROUP BY i.user_id
  )AS j ON(j.user_id = orders.user_id AND orders.created = j.created) GROUP BY orders.user_id
) AS a ON users.id = a.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

For example the SQL request should return this:

```
+--+----+---+--------+
|id|name|sum|date    |
+--+----+---+--------+
 1   A    40  1000005
 2   B    10  1000003
```

But the SQL above failed to calculate sum. What did i miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query seems way too complicated.  How about this?

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, SUM(o.subtotal), MAX(o.created)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON u.id = o.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```

In MySQL it is particularly important to avoid unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  These are actually materialized and that can impede the use of indexes for performance.

Comment: you can also try 
`SELECT u.id, u.name, SUM(o.subtotal), MAX(o.created)
FROM users u, orders o
     WHERE u.id = o.user_id
GROUP BY u.id;`
This query will **ignore the users** whose data is not present in **orders** table.

Comment: @kaushikkaran thanks, but I need the users whose data is not present in `orders` table. I've already fixed the problem with NULL fields by using `COALESCE`.